# Building the release version of UWP project results in error

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp, .net-native

When I activate `.NET Native tool chain` in UWP project targeting `Windows 10, version 1803`, I get these errors:

---

```
Error       Error: NUTC1056:Internal Compiler Error: 0x8000ffff. Error encountered while compiling method 'instance System.Void Premy.Chatovatko.Client.Views.CertificateSelection.InitializeComponent()'.  Premy.Chatovatko.Client.UWP         
Error       ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x86.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\x86\ilc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe @"C:\Chatovatko\Premy.Chatovatko\Premy.Chatovatko.Client\Premy.Chatovatko.Client.UWP\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\Chatovatko.rsp"' returned exit code 1 Premy.Chatovatko.Client.UWP
```

---

The project uses `Xamarin.Forms 3.1.0` and `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.1.7`. (Ths solution is on [Github](https://github.com/stastnypremysl/Chatovatko))

Does anyone has any idea, what can I do with it, please?

Comment: I work near the folks responsible for that component. I've sent them a mail. You can mail me directly if you'd like to get more direct and immediate responses. :-) dotnetnative@microsoft.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reported error here is usually caused when the code attempts to construct a delegate, but the signature of the target method used for the delegate does match the delegate's signature. For example, you have a button in your XAML, and the method used for a button click event does not match the signature of the EventHandler delegate: EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e).

In the Github solution provided above, there are a couple of those mismatches. For instance, Generate() and LoadFromFile() in Premy.Chatovatko.Client.Views.CertificateSelection